# Can I pass parameter to Lightning component in Edit Page -> right panel?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component, which on the right panel of Edit Page, only have `set component visibility`.

Can I also add parameter so that it pass to `<aura:attribute>` tag?

Comment: [Lightning Component Bundle Design Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm)?

Comment: Don't forget to accept glls answer below so other users know that the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what you are looking for is called a design attribute which can be added in the [Lightning Component Bundle Design Resources](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm)

```
<design:component label="Hello World">
    <design:attribute name="subject" label="Subject" description="Name of the person you want to greet" />
    <design:attribute name="greeting" label="Greeting" />
</design:component>
```